# Reboot after apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, reboot

18.04LTS here.

In my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
I have:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

At the same time, `/var/run/reboot-required` exists.

When I exit the server and ssh in again, I can see `* * * System restart required * * *`.

So as far as I can see, the upgrading of packages using apt-get should now trigger an immediate restart if the restart is required, which I know it is (see above two reasons why I believe it is required).

However, I can't trigger the automatic reboot - I would expect it to be triggered by `sudo apt-get upgrade` but the command succeeds successfully and no restart happens.

What am I missing please?

Many thanks!

Contents of /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades :

APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade 1;
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::CleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Verbose "0";

Contents of /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades :
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "+0";

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `update-notifier-common` installed. This is not installed on minimal server installs by default

Comment: I do have it installed...

Comment: what is the conents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

Comment: have you tried setting `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time` just to see whether it reboots?

Comment: I've posted 20auto-upgrades file contents in the question.  Also, trying Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "+0"; or Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "now"; doesn't make much difference.  Running sudo apt-get upgrade doesn't lead to a restart when it should.  Perhaps there is a service that needs to reload the contents of the two conf files?